# Convert html tags to a word document acceptable format

Tags: php, ms-word

Is there a function that converts html tags like `<p></p>` or `<a href>` to word document compatible tags?

I'm using [Microsofts PHP word document creator](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) and I'm putting html into it but it's just being passed to the word document as plain html. I have tried html_entities_decode too but no avail.

Comment: Word can handle HTML no problem, why convert it? The question would be more interesting if it were to ask for a way to get word to generate acceptable HTML... try changing the extension to MHT

Comment: And yet when I place html into the word document using PHPWord, it just puts html tags into the text as plain text rather than formatted? Any ideas?

Comment: [Try with HTML2docx](http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/), I guess the project's title says it all

Comment: After some effing and blinding, I could not understand how to convert one simple string to a word document compatible format. Any ideas? any examples?

Answer (score 0):

[PHPWord](http://phpword.codeplex.com/) is not allowing you to use HTML in the free version.

You need to have a paid version to use the html tags insertion in the Word document.

EDIT:

My mistake, PHPWord doesn't have paid version. I was refering to [PHPDOCX](http://www.phpdocx.com/)
There you can find an optioni inside the paid vesion that will allow you to insert html.

Comment: I can't find the "Paid version" stated there? Do you know where it is?